# application controller in rails for devise account update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am trying to add some additional fields to my edit user section. In the application controller i have been looking at the strong parameters. It worked when i just had the additional name field but now i am adding extra fields it is throwing the following error at me and i am not quite sure what i need to amend here to resolve this.

```
/application_controller.rb:12: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting keyword_end ....for(:account_update) << :name, :line1, :line2, :town, :coun... ... ^


class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

   before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) << :name
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) << :name, :line1, :line2, :town, :county, :postcode
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this :

```
 def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) { |u| u.permit(:name) }
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) { |u| u.permit(name, :line1, :line2, :town, :county, :postcode)}
 end
```

Comment: Thanks this works great! Are you able to give me any explanation as to how this works? Thanks again!